# pymongo: global name 'ReturnDocument' is not defined

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nameerror

I'm trying to write a python program that finds and updates a document in mongodb:

```
db.collection.find_one_and_update({"Machine": "24", "Available": True},
                                  {"$set": {"Overview.Available": False}},
                                  projection= {"_id": 0, "Machine": 1, "Available": 1},
                                  return_document= ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

But I'm getting the following error message (apparently I'm not using return_document correctly but all pymongo documentation says I am)

> NameError: global name 'ReturnDocument' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the `ReturnDocument` class first. Add this to the top of your script:

```
from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
```

Detailed docs: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.ReturnDocument

Comment: Seems to work now, thanks! pymongo and pymongo.collection both seem to work...is one better than the other? what does ".collection" do?

Comment: I have never tried to import it directly from `pymongo`. Always used the documented path.

Comment: Using a smaller package should be more efficient. I'll use pymongo.collection